# Eigenspectrum of $M = A S A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $Q$ be a real-valued, symmetric, and positive definite (PD) matrix, which is partitioned as

$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}
Q_{xx} & Q_{xy} \\
Q_{yx} & Q_{yy}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where diagonal blocks are square. I know, for such a matrix [1], $Q_{xx}$, $Q_{yy}$ and its Schur complement $S=Q_{yy} - Q_{yx} Q_{xx}^{-1} Q_{xy}$ are PD as well. What can I say about $M = A S A^T$ ($A=Q_{xx}^{-1} Q_{xy}$)? My numerical studies shows that it is positive semi-definite, but how can I prove that?

Edit: $Q$ is sparse.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Schur_complement_condition_for_positive_definiteness_and_positive_semidefiniteness

Comment: $M$ can be also positive definite if $Q_{xy}$ has trivial kernel. Do you assume that $Q_{xx}$ and $Q_{yy}$ are symmetric?

Comment: Yes, they are symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $S$ is positive definite and $Q_{xx}$ has full rank and is symmetric. To check definiteness of M lets check if  $v^T M v \geq 0 \ \forall v$. From definition of $M$
$$
v^T M v = v^T Q_{xx}^{-1} Q_{xy} S Q_{xy}^T Q_{xx}^{-1}v.
$$
Now let $w = Q_{xx}^{-1}v$. Since $Q_{xx}$ has full rank it can be interpreted as some change of basis so we can conclude that $v^T M v \geq 0 \ \forall v$ if and only if $w^T Q_{xy} S Q_{xy}^T w \geq 0\ \forall w$.

Now to consider the effect of $Q_{xy}$. In a similar fashion, we can set $z = Q_{xy}^T w$ and substitute. This will produce $z^T S z$. From positive definiteness follows that $z^T S z \geq 0$ and  $z^T S z = 0$ only if $z=0$. From this can be concluded that  $v^T M v \geq 0 \ \forall v$ and $v^T M v = 0$ if and only if $Q_{xy}Q_{xx}^{-1}v = 0$.